# Problem with assigning categories to products using commercejs

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, e-commerce, crud

Can't assign categories to products for an e-commerce project built on Next.js. I can't update the products data, followed the instructions from their API reference but I am confused about the approach I have.

For example, here's the docs about updating an product: https://commercejs.com/docs/api/?shell#update-product

and here is my code to update it:

```
export default async function fetchTemplate(url, method, headers, body) {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    headers: headers,
    body: JSON.stringify(body),
  });
  const data = await response.json();

  return data;
}

export async function updateProductToAPI(productId, body) {
  const product = await fetchTemplate(
    `${productsURL.href}/${productId}`,
    "PUT",
    secretHeaders,
    body
  );

  return product;
}

const prod = {
  description: "some description...",
};

updateProductToAPI("prod_mOVKl493JLwprR", {
  description: "aksjfhkja",
});
```

The data is not updating though. Does anyone here understands the issue?